Getting Debug Message 'Skipped binding property 'IndexModel.Input' since its binding information disallowed it for the current request.'
I have a common base class for all public pages declared as
public class PublicModel : PageModel
{
  [BindProperty]
  public BindingModel Input { get; set; }

  public partial class BindingModel
  {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
}

The Index page inherits from this class
public class IndexModel : PublicModel
{
  // Index page specific logic...
}

Whenever I run the app, I get the message in debug info from the ParameterBinder. In the markup, I'm just using a simple tag-helper
<input asp-for="Input.Username" />

Any idea why the binding is 'disallowed'?

Cannot reproduce your issue. Your code seems to be right and I tested locally with input asp-for in a form, all is good both with post or get method. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. What's more, please check the request information and if you are using a wrong namespace.

I figured it out. I realized none my tag-helpers were working. I had somehow placed a semicolon in my _ViewImports.cshtml file. @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers; Removing the semicolon fixed the issue. There are no compiler errors or warnings for this mistake.
